# shell executed sqoop command error

Tags: shell, sqoop

I want use shell execute sqoop(1.4.5) command.

shell:
sqoop_cmd="sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xx.x.xxx.xxx:3306/test --username test --password datagateway --query 'select t.name from table_name t where date(hrc.gmt_modified) = date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) AND $CONDITIONS'  --target-dir /output  -m 1 --append"

result=`$sqoop_cmd 2>&1 | grep -c "successfully"`

error:
WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.

But I updated --query to --table and remove ' AND $CONDITIONS' param try again, The sqoop command result is successfull. I think the question about '$', but I try '\$CONDITIONS', "'$CONDITIONS'", it's unsuccessfull.

please help me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

this error is cause because 
error: WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
you are entering your database password in the command itself like this **--password datagateway**, instead if you have written like this **-P** you won't get that warning and password will be prompted after you start executing the command

Comment: information about -P otpion is not an error. It is a security suggestion. It will not cause any error.

Comment: I know that its not an error, but some times it served my need it so suggested

Answer (score 0):

When you use --query parameter you have to use $CONDITION and you did it. But you forgot to add --split-by parameter that is obligatory:
From [sqoop user guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports): 
*"Your query must include the token $CONDITIONS which each Sqoop process will replace with a unique condition expression. You must also select a splitting column with --split-by."*

Hope it helps a bit.

Pawel